# ResourceBundle example not working

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I'm trying the example of "Learning Java" about RersourceBundles.

I'm using Windows 7 and NetBeans

The code of the sample is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle bun;
        bun = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Message", Locale.ITALY);
        System.out.println(bun.getString("HelloMessage"));
        bun = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Message", Locale.US);
        System.out.println(bun.getString("HelloMessage"));
    }
}
```

If I run the code I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't
>   find bundle for base name Message, locale it_IT   at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)  at
>   learningjava4.Hello.main(Hello.java:14) Java Result: 1

Even if I wrote and save

```
import java.util.*;
public class Message_it_IT extends ListResourceBundle {
    public Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }
    static final Object[][] contents = {
        {"HelloMessage", "Buon giorno, world!"},
        {"OtherMessage", "Ciao."},
    };
}
```

I still had the same error. The file Message_it_IT was saved on the same directory of the other one, what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the name of your resource bundle file and where it is placed?

Comment: Message_it_IT and saved on the same directory of the other class. Is solved now, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the class is in the package `learningjava4`. And you're telling us that the bundle class/files are in the same package. So the bundle base name is `learningjava4.Message`, not `Message`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast answer! I understand the main thing, but not how to implement the solution. Where do I need to replace "Message" with "learningjava4.Message" inside the text with quotes?

Comment: Solved now! Thanks a lot. The solution was as you say "bun = ResourceBundle.getBundle("learningjava4.Message", Locale.ITALY);"